# VBA Excel get first file name from the files collection returned by GetFolder.Files

Tags: excel, collections, vba

I'm trying to get the first file of a directory. I don't care that "first" is not well defined in this case, and I don't care if I'll get a different file each time I call my sub.

I try to use:

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object

Dim FileItem As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

Set FileItem = SourceFolder.Files.Item(0)
```

but this returns a compiler error ("Invalid procedure call or argument")
Could you please tell me how to make this work?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Did you try with item 1? I think in a collection the first index is 1 and not 0

Comment: @Octavio: Yes I did, got the same error

Comment: `GetFolder` Method accepts a string where as `SourceFolder` is defined as object.

Comment: @Santosh See the code above, GetFolder gets "sourceFolderName" which is a string... sorry, I forgot to add its declaration. I debugged and saw that the error is given on the last code line

Comment: Ah! I overlooked the variable name.

Comment: Interesting Question. Check the last answer from this [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?640484-RESOLVED-Problem-accessing-a-nested-collection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like `SourceFolder.Files` will only accept a string as the key, just like you noted with `Scripting.Folders`. I think Santosh's answer is the way to go, but here's a kludgy modification of your code that returns the "first" file in the folder:

```
Sub test()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim FileItemToUse As Object
Dim SourceFolderName As String
Dim i As Long

SourceFolderName = "C:\Users\dglancy\Documents\temp"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    If i = 0 Then
        Set FileItemToUse = FileItem
        Exit For
    End If
Next FileItem

Debug.Print FileItemToUse.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use the bulit in `Dir` function

Below is the sample code which returns the first file found name from Test folder.

```
Sub test()

    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Dir("D:Test\", vbNormal)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s true that VBA has a limitation (a bug or design flaw in my opinion) in which a file system object's Files collection cannot be accessed by item-index number, only by each item’s file-path string value.  The original question posted here is about accessing only the first item in the Files collection but it touches on a general problem for which there are two reasonable workarounds: creation and use of either a File object meta-collection or a File object array to provide indexed access to a Files collection.  Here’s a demo routine:

```
Sub DemoIndexedFileAccess()
    '
    'Demonstrates use of both a File object meta-collection and a File object array to provide indexed access
    'to a Folder object's Files collection.
    '
    'Note that, in both examples, the File objects being accessed refer to the same File objects as those in
    'the Folder object's Files collection.  (i.e. if one of the physical files gets renamed after the creation
    'of the Folder object's Files collection, all three sets of File objects will refer to the same, renamed
    'file.)
    '
    'IMPORTANT: This technique requires a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" be set.
    '
    '**********************************************************************************************************

    'File-selector dialog contsants for msoFileDialogFilePicker and msoFileDialogOpen:

    Const fsdCancel As Integer = 0       'File dialog Cancel button
    Const fsdAction As Integer = -1      'File dialog Action button, and its aliases...
    Const fsdOpen   As Integer = fsdAction
    Const fsdSaveAs As Integer = fsdAction
    Const fsdOK     As Integer = fsdAction

    Dim FD          As FileDialog
    Dim File        As Scripting.File
    Dim FileArr()   As Scripting.File
    Dim FileColl    As New Collection
    Dim Folder      As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FSO         As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim Idx         As Integer

    'Get a folder specification from which files are to be processed

    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  'Create the FolderPicker dialog object
    With FD
        .Title = "Select Folder Of Files To Be Processed"
        .InitialFileName = CurDir

        If .Show <> fsdOK Then Exit Sub
    End With

    'Use the folder specification to create a Folder object.

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FD.SelectedItems(1))

    'A Folder object's Files collection can't be accessed by item-index number (only by each item's file-path
    'string value), so either...

    '1. Create a generic "meta-collection" that replicates the Files collection's File objects, which allows
    '   access by collection-item index:

        For Each File In Folder.Files
            FileColl.Add File
        Next File

        '"Process" the files in (collection) index order

        For Idx = 1 To FileColl.Count
            Debug.Print "Meta-Collection: " & FileColl(Idx).Name
        Next Idx

    '2. Or, create an array of File objects that refer to the Files collection's File objects, which allows
    '   access by array index:

        ReDim FileArr(1 To Folder.Files.Count)

        Idx = 1
        For Each File In Folder.Files
            Set FileArr(Idx) = File
            Idx = Idx + 1
        Next File

        '"Process" the files in (array) index order

        For Idx = LBound(FileArr) To UBound(FileArr)
            Debug.Print "File Object Array: " & FileArr(Idx).Name
        Next Idx
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem in this Way:

```
Private Function GetFirstFile(StrDrive as String) As String

    'Var Declarations
        Dim Fso As Object, Drive As Object, F As File

    'Create a reference to File System Object and Drive
        Set Fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Set Drive = Fso.GetDrive(StrDrive)
        If Not Drive Is Nothing Then
            'Scan files in RootFolder.files property of then drive object
            For Each F In Drive.RootFolder.Files
                Exit For
            Next
            'if there are any file, return the first an get then name
            If Not F Is Nothing Then FirstFile = F.Name: Set F = Nothing
            Set Drive = Nothing
        End If
        Set Fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Don´t forget add Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in your project
It works to me... I hope this Help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a function to iterate through the files in the folder until you get to the one that you want? Assuming you're using the fso as detailed in other posts above, just pass the Folder, and the Index of the file you want, it could be #1 or any other file in the folder.

```
Function GetFile(oFolder As Folder, Index As Long) As File
Dim Count As Long
Dim oFile As File
  Count = 0
  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = Index Then
      Set GetFile = oFile
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next oFile
End Function
```